# String Value to set an Enum

Tags: java, enums, model, value-of

I would like to set an enum type by using one of its values as an input :

This is the code i'm using,

```
    package models;

    import models.crudsiena.SienaSupport;
    import siena.*;

    public class Item extends SienaSupport {

        @Id
        public Long id;


           public static enum Type{
              A,
              B
            };

            public Type itemType;

            public Item(String itemType) {
               this.itemType = Type.valueOf(itemType);
            }
}
```

When I try to use `new Item("A")` it returns me a `NullPointerException occured : Name is null`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: as Jon said, the problem must be somewhere else, the code you have posted should work well.

Comment: hi thanks for your time, I'm going to add more in a sec sorry for that. This is the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/xBjBm4pM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Item(String itemType) {
   if (itemType == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("null itemType");
   }
   this.itemType = Type.valueOf(itemType);
}
```

Comment: I just tried and It returned me the null itemType exception so there must be something wrong with my input